# Can joins effectively ignore field indexes if they are a constant?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

It is much easier to explain this with an example.

> Table A has PK on (store,line).
>   Table B has PK on (id,store,line).
>   [id] is int, [store] is nvarchar(100) and [line] is int in both cases.

If I run:

```
select * 
from A inner join B 
on A.store=B.store and A.line=B.line
where B.id=0
```

will the engine be able to make a fast (i'm thinking merge) join? Or will it be helpful to add a dummy column `id` valued 0 in A?

Comment: Just check this....https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/986a3009-bb5b-4acc-9f6a-772f5dbd698f/join-on-varchar-vs-join-on-int?forum=transactsql

Comment: @Pankaj_Dwivedi-- that has nothing to do with this quesiton

Comment: The _actual execution plan_ will show what the optimizer chose. There is no reason to add a column to `A`. Instead of using a `where` clause you could simply add the `id` condition to the `on` clause.

Comment: Why not test this yourself?

Comment: There is no point to discussing hypothetical performance questions. The answer to any performance question is always "it depends". Because it depends on the actual query, the DDL of the objects involved, the distribution of values in the joined columns, statistics, etc. And as already suggested by MJH just test it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement will work but if you do it like this the optimizer will be more effective:

```
select * 
from A inner
join B on A.store=B.store and A.line=B.line and B.id=0
```

Here is is able to exclude items where b.id does not equal zero before it does the merge.  Depending on table size topology etc this could be quite significant.

For example consider the case where you have 50 million rows shared across 5 nodes table b and 1 node for table a -- in your code all records would have to be moved to the node with the a table while with the code above only the records that have id = 0 would need to be moved.

This can be very non-intuitive when a is a small table (which are often only on one node.)

Comment: No matter where the condition will be, when inner join is used

Comment: I don't understand @DenisRubashkin

Comment: I mean that optimizer will produce the same query plans for both cases either `B.id=0` is in the where clause or in join

Comment: @DenisRubashkin --- I know this is not the case for all platforms.  I've not worked specifically with SQL server recently with a case like this and I don't have access to one right now, however as we move to the cloud we can assume that data is sharded and it would matter as I describe above.  This is also a simple case -- the optimizer might be able to see that there is no difference here but consider the case where there are many more joins and sub-queries -- then the optimizer would have to respect the logical difference.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin -- you may be confusing this issue up with a different one that happens in the where clause.  -- You have a left join and turn it to an inner join by referencing a value in the where turning it into an inner join.  You are right -- this is not like that one, but it is similar -- it does fundamentally change how data is accessed when it is retrieved from the joined table.  Unlike in the left join case it does not change the results -- but it can have a significant impact on performance.